# Access variable values outside "done" method in ParseQuery in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, encapsulation

I have a parse query and need to use the results of the query throughout my app and am only able to view/access them in the done method in the ParseQuery

```
    query.whereWithinKilometers("coordinates", new ParseGeoPoint(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()),1000);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> roomList, ParseException e) {
           //I can access roomList here no problem
           //I need to use it everywhere but can't get the values out
}
```

Above is my query, I can only use roomList while it is in the done method. roomList begins and ends in there! I need a way to get the object outside of this.

I have tried calling a method from inside there,
I have tried using sttatic variables, public variables..all with no luck.

Please help!

Comment: Why aren't member variables working?

Comment: It seems like a non-blocking call. Maybe within the listener you could persist it by saving to a database etc. I still believe that member variables will work.